# .deb package: cannot upload to Bintray when package is build using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: packaging, deb

so I am trying to upload my package that I compiles and build on a machine running 18.04 to Bintray.

It doesn't work. I get a message like this:

```
Unable to upload files: Could not extract metadata for artifact 'pool/m/myapp/myapp_1.0~bionic1_amd64.deb', content might be malformed.
```

I tried installing the package and no issues with that. I also tried getting the package information using:

```
dpkg-deb --build myapp_1.0~bionic1_amd64.deb
```

and no problem with that either.

This is the command I use to build the package:

```
dpkg-deb --build myapp_1.0~bionic1_amd64
```

If I build the package using 16.04 (booted off LiveDVD) and ran the same command, I can upload the .deb without any issues.

I've tried 1 other repo (cannot remember the exact site but it starts with "gem") and I get the same error.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thank

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but Ubuntu 18.04 use dpkg 1.19.0, which use per default uniform compression. Maybe Travis CI doesn't support it.

> --[no-]uniform-compression
>
> Specify that the same compression parameters should be used for all archive members (i.e. control.tar  and  data.tar;  since  dpkg  1.17.6). Otherwise  only  the  data.tar member will use those parameters. The only supported compression types allowed to be uniformly used are none, gzip and xz.  The --no-uniform-compression option disables uniform compression (since dpkg 1.19.0). Uniform  compression  is  the  default (since dpkg 1.19.0).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is [indeed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446263/320370) in the compression used in the `control` part of the package:

```
$ ar t example.deb # 16.04
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.xz

$ ar t example.deb # 18.04
debian-binary
control.tar.xz
data.tar.xz
```

Bintray still doesn't support packages created on Ubuntu 18.04.

It is possible to workaround this issue by specifying options to [dh_builddeb](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/17/how-to-create-debian-packages-with-alternative-compression-methods/) in the `debian/rules` file:

```
override_dh_builddeb:
        dh_builddeb -- --no-uniform-compression
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature would be welcome in bintray?

I pinged them at:
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9656

Stay tuned